# Upsert a post in mongodb with c# save without removing old values that are non existing in the new item

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to upsert an existing document in mongoDB with the save method in c#.

This works well if the new item includes all the attributes of the old item. But if the new item does not contain all the old attributes, the attributes not included in the new item will be erased from the old item. Is there some way to keep the old values?

The behaviour I want is this:

If olditem contains attribute and new does not - keep old value

If olditem contains attribute and newitem  also - keep new value

If olditem does not contain attribute but newitem does - keep new value.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in c# using omu.valueinjecter

`protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            bool retval = (
              c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name) 
              && (c.SourceProp.Value != null 
              && c.TargetProp.Value == null);
            return retval;
        }`